# How to install solr 6.x with Homebrew?

Tags: macos, solr, homebrew, solr6

I want to install solr 6.6.1 and solr 6.4.1 with homebrew on my Mac.

With `brew install solr`, by default version 8 is installed.

With `brew search solr` i can only find solr versions 7.7 & 8. How do i install older versions?

I would like to be able to switch between which version of the service is running with homebrew.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me that Homebrew only keeps the last two versions. With Homebrew 1.9.2 I see Solr 6 and 5 whereas with Homebrew 2.1.1 I see Solr 7 and 8:

```
$ brew --version
Homebrew 1.9.2
Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision b7182; last commit 2019-01-22)
Homebrew/homebrew-cask (git revision 44e62; last commit 2019-01-22)

$ brew search solr
==> Formulae
solr                                               
solr@6.6                                           
homebrew/linuxbrew-core/solr@7.7
solr@5.5                                           
homebrew/linuxbrew-core/solr

$ brew update
# (ton's of information here)

$ brew --version
Homebrew 2.1.1
Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision c116f; last commit 2019-04-24)
Homebrew/homebrew-cask (git revision efc7e; last commit 2019-04-24)

$ brew search solr
==> Formulae
solr                                                                         
solr@7.7
```

I am not sure if there is a way to fetch older versions. I realize this does not fully answer the question but it was too long for a comment.

Comment: Thanks - that's helpful, but ideally i'd like to be able to install more than two versions with the most recent homebrew...

Answer (score 0):

One can Install Solr@6.6 from here:

```
brew tap-new $USER/solr
brew extract --version=6.6 solr $USER/solr
brew search /solr/
brew install <user local formula path>
```